# Verbs that collocate with of

Tags: usage, collocations

Is it grammatically correct to say that something or someone radiates of love. I know that we use *of* with verbs such as approve, smell and consist, but what other verbs collocate with *of*, and is *radiate* one of them?

Answer (score 2):

No. Unfortunately, in the context you mention "radiate" does not require a preposition, so "radiate of" isn't correct.

> He radiates happiness.
>
> She radiates beauty.

If you stick with certain verbs of senses, you can find a pattern of verbs you can use in the same way of "smell", and they can be used literally or figuratively.

> He smells of must (Lit)
>
> This smells of a cover-up (Fig)

"Smell" has some openly negative synonyms (exclusively for describing bad smells/situations).

> This **reeks** of disaster (Fig)
>
> She stinks of cigarette smoke (Lit)

I know your question asked for a list of verbs that collocate with "of" but that's a very general question. You are better off finding an appropriate verb for what you want to express and then finding the necessary preposition. I hope this has helped you.